# mediaelement js audio player not playing mp3 file in IE 9,10

Tags: mediaelement.js

Hi I am getting an error "Unsupported audio type or invalid file path " error on the mediaelementjs audio player

I went to mediaelementjs official website and found that their demo audio player on the website main page is not working in ie 9,10.

Can anyone tell if mediaelementjs player work with ie at all? or what codec required for mp3 files which are able to run on ie browsers version 9 and later.

I have adobe flash player ver. 14 for ie.

Comment: aren't you using any compatibility mode? ... does this work for you in IE[9-10] http://jsfiddle.net/7vWuT/1/show ?

Comment: No they don't work on my IE 9 and 10. Its mediaelementjs player. I visited their website and audio player there don't play audio on my ie 9,10 as well. What could be missing?

Comment: it works on mine, so it might be your IE installation/settings specifically

Comment: Can you please share your such settings, so that I can relax? Maybe i would need to add a functionality on website for checking those settings.

Comment: maybe you can try testing in another computer

Comment: BTW, do you have installed a local web server like Tomcat or so?

Comment: I have WAMP server installed on my local. And I am testing it online as well. Maybe there's problem with my IE but what problem could it be? when I try to play the file directly in IE, browser trigger media player and play file in it. Though it should have played in the browser like other browsers do. Personally I don't use IE much so not sure how it should run. But for testing I have to use IE as well.

Comment: Its not working on Mac IE as well.